# How do I update ink data of onenote pages using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365, microsoft-graph-teams, onenote-api, microsoft365

I am trying to build an application interacting with onenote using Microsoft Graph API. I found a official blog [OneNote Ink BETA Apis](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/onenote/blogs/onenote-ink-beta-apis/) talking about how to get ink data from pages and how to create pages with ink data, but it didn't address how to update ink data. [Update OneNote page content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/onenote-update-page) talks only about how to update the HTML page of onenote(not the ink part). I wonder is there any way to update ink data(add, delete or change ink traces) ?

Also, there are no more ink related document or blog posted since [OneNote Ink BETA Apis](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/onenote/blogs/onenote-ink-beta-apis/). But I found this API is still availiable in 1.0 version of MS Graph. So why these set of API are undocumented ? Will they get futher support or will be deprecated or become unavailable in the future ?

Thanks!

Comment: As far as I know there is no such feature as of now in Microsoft Graph. You can raise a feature request in [Microsoft Graph Feedback Forum](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests) so that the product team may implement it in future."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope the ink APIs stay as I use them in my poduction code (they are out of beta). I have asked this question before and the response at the time was that updating page ink data was not supported. My workaround is to build an entirely new page with the new ink data (and old data) and then to delete the orginal page - far from ideal!