# Use OneNote GraphAPI to insert handwritten notes

Tags: microsoft-graph-onenote

Good Evening,
I am trying to insert handwritten notes into OneNote pages (specifically OneNote for Windows 10) using the OneNote GraphAPI. Basically i'm looking for a way to insert a set of points or splines depending on how OneNote represents them internally. With *handwritten notes* being the main feature of OneNote, and images and text begin well supported, i'm sure there is a way to insert notes into pages. Since i couldn't find anything related to handwritten notes in the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/graph/integrate-with-onenote), i'm asking you:

- Is it possible to insert handwritten notes into OneNote pages via the
  GraphAPI and if so how exactly does that work?
- If its impossible, i'd be very glad to hear about other programmatic ways of inserting
  handwritten notes aswell (although at first glance it would be
  extremely odd for such a basic feature to be missing). Is there maybe
  some way to embed it into HTML and serve it via the clipboard?

Otherwise, the application will have to resort to dragging the mouse pointer using the Windows API which is really error-prone, inefficient and doesn't work on phones.

Thank you in advance and i'm looking forward to your takes,
Erik

Answer (score 0):

How to do this is documented [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/microsoft365dev/onenote-ink-beta-apis/).
The limitations of using the ink APIs is documented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65791957/how-do-i-update-ink-data-of-onenote-pages-using-microsoft-graph-api/65829868#65829868).
Unfortunately, as far as I know, you still cannot append ink to a page using the GraphAPI - it can only be added at page creation.